# Метод Update в Битрикс D7

Tags: битрикс, orm

Здравствуйте. Подскажите, можно ли в Битрикс D7 использовать вычисление при методе update?

Например:

```
$result2 = OrderTable::update(1, array(
            'BALANCE' => 'Вот тут мне нужно ВЫЧЕСТЬ например число 10 из существующего значения этого поля',
        ));
```

Это возможно штатными средствами ORM, или придется огород городить с получением предыдущего значения и вычисления перед update?

Comment: А использовать событие "OnBeforeOrderUpdate" почему не подходит?

Comment: Редакция "Старт", модуля интернет магазина соответственно нет. Поэтому свой огород городить приходится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если класс (как я понимаю самодельный) OrderTable создан с использованием D7 (т.е. унаследован от \Bitrix\Main\Entity\DataManager) то он поддерживает механизм событий. Следовательно вы можете подвязаться на необходимое при помощи обработчика.

Т.е. у вас есть событие onBeforeAdd и onBeforeUpdate. Подробности есть в [курсах Битрикс](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/index.php?COURSE_ID=43&LESSON_ID=2244#events)

Comment: Если я правильно понял мне нужны не события а вычисляемые значения:  `OrderTable::update($id, array(
    'BALANCE' => new DB\SqlExpression('?# + ?i', 'BALANCE', $count)
));`  Так?